# "Same thing happened to me" versus "Same thing happened with me"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> The same thing happened to me.

OR

> The same thing happened with me.

Which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: Though I think both are correct, but the first sentence is more common.

Comment: What happened? It depends on context. If someone just said "I got hit by a bus.", the first is definitely more apt. If someone just said "it really annoys me when people bite their pencil" ,the second would be better.

Answer (score 4):

Which one is grammatically correct? **Both**.

However, [the former one seems to be common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=same%20thing%20happened%20to%20me%2Csame%20thing%20happened%20with%20me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csame%20thing%20happened%20to%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csame%20thing%20happened%20with%20me%3B%2Cc0) in use.

---

Just my opinion:

If things happen *to* you, you are a ***bit*** passive.

> Something happened ***to*** her and she started screaming.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to/with me.

When something happens to somebody or something, it takes place and affects them.

I don't know what's happened to Adam.

If anything happens to the the car, you will have to pay for it.

According to The Free Dictionary, in sentences like these, don't use any other preposition except "to".

Besides, I don't think we can find the preposition "with" in any reliable books. Second, according to Ngram presented by Maulik,its use is rare or almost nil.

In light of the above, I think we should avoid using the preposition "with", though rarely used,